# C# WebBrowser PanningMode

Tags: c#, scroll, touch, webbrowser-control

I'm working on a WinForms application that is implementing a C# WebBrowser control. This application is deploying to a Windows 7 SP1 Panasonic touch screen device.

Many times, the user will be browsing a page containing a very large image. In order to see parts of this image, they will need to scroll horizontally. While the vertical scrolling via finger is fine, horizontal scrolling is very uncooperative.

I see we have [ScrollViewer.SetPanningMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.setpanningmode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but do we have something similar for the WebBrowser?

**Question**: Can we achieve smooth horizontal touch scrolling for a WebBrowser control?

When the image isn't high enough for vertical scrolling, it becomes impossible to scroll horizontally.

Comment: If you know the html to the pages, can you not add a style to the image ? like default widhth =200px or something ?

Comment: Because the user needs to see the detail. They just need to be able to scroll right without scrolling down first.

Comment: This is even more of a problem when an image stretches horizontally past the browser window, but is not tall enough to stretch the page vertically. When this is the case, it is impossible to scroll right on a Windows Mobile device.

Comment: Maybe this link and sample will be helpfull? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920761(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Could you clarify whether IE10 can be a requirement for this project and whether you want scrollbars still be visible when showing the image.

Comment: First of all which version of WebBrowser are you using (.NET Version). Secondly does it behave the same in Browser only too? By this I mean the same version which you are using in the WebBrowser. You should get that by the property Version of the Control.

Comment: @zewa666, I presume it is WPF WebBrowser(?) as `ScrollViewer.SetPanningMode` was mentioned.

Comment: Yep but those implement different versions of IE based on the NET framework used. So id recommand testing the page in that specific IE first to see if it is a HTML/CSS specific issue.

Comment: This is unfortunately a Win Forms application.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, I have a solution to this panning problem. It does require IE10 (Desktop), but I remember reading  in the comments (was it deleted?) that the target platform for this project is Windows 7, so hopefully you have freedom to deploy IE10 there. I tested it with my old  Asus Eee PC T91MT (Windows 7 SP1 w/ [Platform Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838) and [IE10](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-10-details.aspx)) and it felt pretty good even on that piece of hardware.

Grab a working VS2012 project for [WinForms](http://goo.gl/ZP6dCB) or [WPF](http://goo.gl/mrgBon).

The major points are:

- Enable [IE10 document mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation) for `WebBrowser` control.
- Disable [IE Legacy Input Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#legacy_input) for `WebBrowser` control.
- Use [IE10-specific touch CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh920761%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as other fellow readers have suggested.

Code (C#):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace WpfWbApp
{
    //
    // By Noseratio [http://stackoverflow.com/users/1768303/noseratio]
    //
    // Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170011/c-sharp-webbrowser-panningmode
    //

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            SetBrowserCompatibilityMode();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
            this.WB.LoadCompleted += WB_LoadCompleted;
        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WB.Navigate(new Uri(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase), "content/test.htm").AbsoluteUri);
        }

        void WB_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.WB.Focus();
            this.WB.InvokeScript("focus");
        }

        private void SetBrowserCompatibilityMode()
        {
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

            // FeatureControl settings are per-process
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

            if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0) // make sure we're not running inside Visual Studio
                return;

            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            {
                // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
                UInt32 mode = 10000; // 10000; 
                key.SetValue(fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }

            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BLOCK_LMZ_SCRIPT",
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            {
                // enable <scripts> in local machine zone
                UInt32 mode = 0;
                key.SetValue(fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }

            using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE",
                RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
            {
                // disable Legacy Input Model
                UInt32 mode = 0;
                key.SetValue(fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfWbApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Touch and pan the picture" Width="1024" Height="800">
    <WebBrowser Name="WB"></WebBrowser>
</Window>
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body { -ms-content-zooming:none; -ms-scroll-rails: none; }  
</style>
</head>
<body style="overflow: auto">
<img src="panorama.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

I could not test it with IE9 as I don't have a touch-screen machine with IE9, although I'm sure it would not work. Apparently, the new [Pointer Events Touch API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673557%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) was introduced for Windows 7 (with [Platform Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838)) [specifically for IE10](http://www.techspot.com/news/51757-internet-explorer-10-finally-arrives-on-windows-7.html).

Let us know how it works for you. Good luck!

**[EDITED]**
Updated with a link to [a WinForms project](http://goo.gl/ZP6dCB).

Comment: This is a Windows Forms application, but i'll see if I can't get this working for it.

Comment: I've ran your project and made my own version of it and panning horizontally with the finger still doesn't work unless I scroll down (vertical first). I installed IE10 on the Win7 SP1 device. I am using a random site for testing: http://pic.templetons.com/cgi-bin/imget?f=brad/pano/midpano/center-wide.jpg&fw=15547

Comment: Does your Win7 have Platform Update installed? If so, have you tried my project as is (it includes a panoramic picture) with IE10 and it still doesn't work?

Comment: I have VS2010 so I can't open your project as is. But making a VS2010 project with your code and your file yields the same results. I'm not sure if the handheld has Platform Update. But if it doesn't, I can't install it. The device I'm using is an image from a large company and even convincing them to upgrade to IE10 is something that will likely not happen. If the only way to achieve this is through updates, then I won't be able to test this since I am not in control of the web sites the user is going to browse and I am not in control of the devices other software.

Comment: Dragging horizontally on the image picks up the image like I'm trying to drag and drop it somewhere. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: No problem. I wonder how my Win7 tablet PC is different from your hardware, but things like this happen all the time. I also tried it on a Win8 touch-screen laptop, where it worked very smoothly. Anyway, that's the best I could do.

Comment: Sure does. Internet Explorer - Reliably unreliable.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty, mate, albeit the answer did not really deserve it. Good luck with your project.