# Touch capable webbrowser control for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I am having a problem with embedding webbrowser in WPF application.
As you may know the standard webbrowser is not really a WPF component.
When you embed the control you cannot apply any transforms on it and is displayed on the topmost layer as it is just wrapper for winforms control.

I have to create app with webbrowser included; the app should rotate to face all four edges of the touch capable screen that will be built into the restaurant table.
I've tried Awesomium and CefSharp but touch scrolling works only in winforms components (which is weird cause WPF was designed with touch in mind).

Any ideas? Alternative WPF browser components? The component has to WPF control, be touch responsive and preferably free or cheap.

Answer (score 1):

If it is still relevant, there is a way to make `WPF WebBrowser` control touch-friendly (IE10+), [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18249567/1768303).

Comment: This is relevant but it is not the solution because the `WebBrowser` control is not real WPF control so it is immune to geometric transformations. I leave tihs question unanswered until the CefSharp is proven to be fully touch capable (seems like it will happen soon)

Comment: @Peuczyński, I on the same page with you. Microsoft really should have provided a managed version of WebBrowser, especially given the fact they already have `WebView` for WP.