# touch enabled wpf web browser control

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, webbrowser-control, pixelsense

I have to create x64 wpf app with webbrowser included, the app should rotate/scale to face all four edges of the touch capable screen that will be built into the table. Suggest me some alternatives to native wpf web browser control. tutorials much appreciated.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119125/options-for-embedding-chromium-instead-of-ie-webbrowser-control-with-wpf-c) are some thoughts on the alternatives. If however you are not happy about the stock WebBrowser only because its touch UI doesn't behave as expected, check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170011/c-sharp-webbrowser-panningmode/18249567#18249567)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to rotate things, Awesomium (as mentioned in @Noeratto's comment) is the only real game in town