# Browser embedded in WPF not handling pointer events

Tags: wpf, winforms, browser, touch

I am hosting a WebBrowser control in a Windows 7 WPF application.

Now I am having a problem with the javascript running within this browser. The DOM `pointer` events are not firing. When I click a DOM object, the `mousedown` and `click` events fire, but the `pointerdown` event does not fire, even though it fires when viewing the same page in Internet Explorer 11.

How can I make the DOM `pointerdown` events fire?

Here's what I see in the browser:

[image: Browser image]

Here's what I see in the WPF application:

[image: WPF Image]

Here's the HTML document I'm testing with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Raw test page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mouseTarget{
            border: 2px solid purple;
            background: steelblue;
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mouseTarget">Mouse Target</div>
    <div id="logOutput"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var logOutput = function (text) {
            $("<div></div>").text(text).appendTo($("#logOutput"));
        };
        var mouseTarget = document.getElementById('mouseTarget');
        mouseTarget.addEventListener('pointerdown', function () {
            logOutput('pointerdown event received');
        }, false);
        mouseTarget.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
            logOutput('mousedown event received');
        }, false);
        mouseTarget.addEventListener('click', function () {
            logOutput('click event received');
        }, false);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Sorry it seems the setting isn't enough to FIRE the pointer events. Its just recognizing touch events but still only firing the mouse events. Very annoying...

---

The problem is that WebBrowser control isn't acting like a usual IE instance. First of all its using a legacy fallback IE7 mode by default. Other points are a legacy input model and some more.

I personally had the issue to set the browserMode to IE10 but pointer events where not working at all. The issue was, that the WebBrowser control pretended to support PointerEvents which I subscribed but due to an enabled legacy input model these were'nt fired.

You can set these policies dynamically from within you application for just that application :

```
private void SetBrowserCompatibilityMode()
    {
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx

        // FeatureControl settings are per-process
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);

        if (String.Compare(fileName, "devenv.exe", true) == 0) // make sure we're not running inside Visual Studio
            return;

        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
        {
            // Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE10 Standards mode.
            UInt32 mode = 10000; // 10000; or 11000 if IE11 is explicitly supported as well
            key.SetValue(fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

        using (var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_NINPUT_LEGACYMODE",
            RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
        {
            // disable Legacy Input Model
            UInt32 mode = 0;
            key.SetValue(fileName, mode, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
        }

    }
```

Refer to: [C# WebBrowser PanningMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170011/c-sharp-webbrowser-panningmode/18249567#18249567)